# can gwt be used with other languages other than java?

Tags: java, frameworks, toolkit

I am planning to study on gwt but after going through some introductions, it seems to be tightly coupled with java. (which people say is already dying)

can gwt be teamed up with languages like c or php? or other languages at all?

Comment: "On a long enough timeline the survival rate for everything drops to zero."

Comment: For what it's worth, it's on the downswing, but it's generally been the #1 or #2 most popular langauge over the last few years:  http://www.tiobe.com/index.php/content/paperinfo/tpci/index.html

Comment: Seriously? Don't worry about Java dying. It'll probably outlast most "new and trendy" languages given the size of the install and developer base and the huge amount of money companies have invested in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to wikipedia, yes.  It has been ported to python and ruby.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Web_Toolkit